# Action h:commandButton «Unable to find matching navigation case»

Tags: jsf-2

I have these JSF files:

*index-implicit.xhtml*:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Working with implicit and explicit conversion</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputText value="Insert your age:"/><br />
    <h:form id="AgeForm">
        <h:inputText id="userAgeID" required="true" value="#{userBean.userAge}">
        </h:inputText>
        <h:message showSummary="true" showDetail="false" for="userAgeID"
                   style="color: red; text-decoration:overline"/>
        <br />
        <h:commandButton id="submit" action="response-implicit?faces-redirect=true" value="Submit Age"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

And *response-implicit.xhtml*:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Working with implicit and explicit conversion</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputText value="Inserted age: "/>
    <h:outputText value="#{userBean.userAge}"/>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Next, I execute *index-implicit.xhtml*, enter a Age, and when I click on commandButton (*Submit Age*), this message appears twice:

`Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id '/age-conversion/index-implicit.xhtml' for action 'response-implicit?faces-redirect=true' with outcome 'response-implicit?faces-redirect=true'`

So, I have created another file, *response.xhtml* (with the same content as *response-implicit.xhtml*), and changed ***action="response?faces-redirect=true"*** in *index-implicit.xhtml* and it works correctly.

Some idea about this issue? Why request works with response.xhtml?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.:

Additional info.:

- I have included PrimeFaces and ICEfaces to the Web Application Project (NetBeans)
- I'm using GlassFish 3 App Server

Comment: `response-response` is not the same as `response-implicit`. Is this the real code or just carelessness?

Comment: @BalusC, what I need to know is why `action="response-implicit?faces-redirect=true"` does not work?

Comment: @JohnOrtiz, by your design, what is `response-response` supposed to be? A JSF navigation rule outcome or the name of a view?

Comment: @kolossus, sorry, it is a typo. I corrected it. It is `action="response-implicit?faces-redirect=true"`.

Comment: @JohnOrtiz ,  PrimeFaces and ICEfaces in same project ??? You aware that IceFaces is copy/paste of OLD Primefacs ?

Comment: @JohnOrtiz, your code post is titled **responde-implicit.xhtml** but within your markup, you're asking for a navigation to **response-implicit**. Typo?

Comment: @kolossus, is a typo. I have removed it.

Comment: Okay. In the future be more careful about the carelessness... In any way, I am unable to reproduce your problem with Mojarra 2.1.16. What JSF impl/version are you using? The Glassfish-bundled one? That'll be Mojarra. Read webapp startup log for the exact version.

Comment: @BalusC, I'm using JSF 2.1. The Glassfish bundled one.

Comment: "JSF 2.1" is the specification version. It's like saying "A German car" instead of "BMW E39 M5". There are two major implementations "Mojarra" and "MyFaces". They are available in various 2.1.x versions. Currently latest Mojarra is 2.1.16. Which one are you using? Again, read the webapp startup log as explicitly asked in my previous comment.